# How do I go about enabling HTTP proxy in Twitty Twister?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm using the [twittytwister](https://github.com/dustin/twitty-twister) module to implement a Twitter client but it looks like it's no longer being developed. I need to connect to an HTTP proxy to be able to reach the internet but the module does not have such an option so I'm looking at modifying it.

```
def __downloadPage(factory, *args, **kwargs):
    downloader = factory(*args, **kwargs)
    if downloader.scheme == 'https':
        from twisted.internet import ssl
        contextFactory = ssl.ClientContextFactory()
        reactor.connectSSL(downloader.host, downloader.port,
                           downloader, contextFactory)
    else:
        reactor.connectTCP(downloader.host, downloader.port,
                           downloader)
    return downloader

def getPage(url, *args, **kwargs):
    return __downloadPage(client.HTTPClientFactory, url, *args, **kwargs)
```

What can I do here to make it connect with my proxy? Do I replace client.HTTPClientFactory with something else?

Answer (score 0):

The newer (added in Twisted 9.0.0) HTTP client API, `twisted.web.client.Agent`, includes support for connecting to an HTTP proxy.  For example, you could write:

```
from twisted.web.client import Agent, ProxyAgent
from twisted.internet.endpoints import clientFromString
from twisted.internet import reactor

from os import environ

try:
    proxy = environ["HTTP_PROXY"]
except KeyError:
    agent = Agent(reactor)
else:
    agent = ProxyAgent(clientFromString(reactor, proxy))
```

See the [endpoints documentation](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/endpoints.html) for details about the expected format of the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable this example uses.

Unfortunately it looks like twittytwister uses the older HTTP client API so you'll need to port it to use `Agent` before you can benefit from `ProxyAgent`.  Fortunately the `getPage` style API is fairly limited so it shouldn't be very hard to replace it with `Agent`-style code.

Comment: Is there another way other than using ProxyAgent? twittytwister looks like it's using a mix of both. Porting it fully to the new API seems complicated.